# How To Get Log Level in Json with Serilog - .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, serilog

I am new to `Serilog` and I am trying to determine how to send a serialized `json` to the `console` with a `log level` and `date time` field. There doesn't seem to be any info in the docs under `structured data`.

Here is my code that is called in the `Startup.cs`:

```
private void LoggerLoop(ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    RabbitModel rb = new RabbitModel
    {
        Id = 1,
        DeviceNum = 1,
        DeviceName = "Device 1",
        InputNum = 1,
        InputName = "Input 1",
        InputState = 1,
        OnPhrase = "On",
        OffPhrase = "Off",
        When = "2020-01-01T22:45:00.1124303+00:00"
    };

    while (true)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("{@rb}", rb);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

And here is my output:

`[14:28:22 INF] {"Id": 1, "DeviceNum": 1, "DeviceName": "Device 1", "InputNum": 1, "InputName": "Input 1", "InputState": 1, "OnPhrase": "On", "OffPhrase": "Off", "When": "2020-01-01T22:45:00.1124303+00:00", "$type": "RabbitModel"}`

I did notice that its added a field `$type` and wondered if this is possible for the `[14:28:22 INF]` to be added to the `json`?

Comment: Why do you need that data in json?

Comment: I especially want the log level and the rest in `json` because I wan't to be able to use it with Elasticsearch

Comment: Use [Elasticsearch sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch) for that. It will automatically convert all log data to json (elastic format). You can direct write to elastic, or write to console with `ElasticsearchJsonFormatter`, but then you need something that will collect logs and send it to elastic. It can be fluentd if you use containers

Comment: Thanks, yes I am running everything from containers.  I was planning on sending `json` to `Filebeat` via `Docker` containers that then sent that data to Elasticsearch.

Comment: I'll describe our flow: according to [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) all logs writes to `stdout` (console) in elasticsearch format, then we have kubernetes cluster with installed [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) which collect all logs from containers (by filter) and send it to the Elastic. All logs are [structured](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/06/structured-logging-concepts-in-net-series-1/), it improves searching in Kibana

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Thats very similar to what I need (without Kubernetes) but the burning question is, how do you get the log(s)  from `stdout` in an elasticsearch format??

Comment: Do you mean how to write elasticsearch formatted log to stdout?

Comment: Yes, in fact I've just landed on this page: github.com/serilog/….  I am using `appsettings.json` to configure `Serilog` and I have read up to the `appsettings.json` configuration in the docs but all the `Args` dont make much sense in my case.  It appears to be making a direct connection to Elasticsearch if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/logs), application should writes all logs to `stdout`/`stderr`.

Then you need collect all logs together, and route to one or more final destinations for viewing ([Elasticserach](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch)). Open-source log routers (such as [FluentBit](https://www.fluentd.org/), [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) and [Logplex](https://github.com/heroku/logplex)) are available for this purpose.

So, the app never concerns itself with routing or storage of its logs. In dotnet app You can easily achieve it using [Serilog](https://serilog.net/)

Let's say we have the following logger settings in *appsettings.json*

```
"Logging": {
    "OutputFormat": "console",
    "MinimumLevel": "Information"
}
```

We can create an extension method

```
private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder() =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseLogging();
}
```

that can write logs to the console in both plain text and elasticsearch format. Plain text logs will be useful for development, because it is more human readable. On Production we enable elasticsearch format and see all logs only in Kibana.

The code of extension with comments:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseLogging(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder, string applicationName = null) =>
    webHostBuilder
        .UseSetting("suppressStatusMessages", "True") // disable startup logs
        .UseSerilog((context, loggerConfiguration) =>
        {
            var logLevel = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:MinimumLevel"); // read level from appsettings.json
            if (!Enum.TryParse<LogEventLevel>(logLevel, true, out var level))
            {
                level = LogEventLevel.Information; // or set default value
            }

            // get application name from appsettings.json
            applicationName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(applicationName) ? context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("App:Name") : applicationName;

            loggerConfiguration.Enrich
                .FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Is(level)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", applicationName);

            // read other Serilog configuration
            loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);

            // get output format from appsettings.json. 
            var outputFormat = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:OutputFormat");
            switch (outputFormat)
            {
                case "elasticsearch":
                    loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Console(new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter());
                    break;
                default:
                    loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Console(
                        theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code,
                        outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sssZ} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{Environment}{Application}/{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}");
                    break;
            }
        });
```

When `OutputFormat` is `elasticsearch` the log will be like

> {"@timestamp":"2020-02-07T16:02:03.4329033+02:00","level":"Information","messageTemplate":"Get
>   customer by id: {CustomerId}","message":"Get customer by id:
>   20","fields":{"CustomerId":20,"SourceContext":"Customers.Api.Controllers.CustomerController","ActionId":"c9d77549-bb25-4f87-8ea8-576dc6aa1c57","ActionName":"Customers.Api.Controllers.CustomerController.Get
>   (Customers.Api)","RequestId":"0HLTBQP5CQHLM:00000004","RequestPath":"/v1/customers","CorrelationId":"daef8849b662117e","ConnectionId":"0HLTBQP5CQHLM","Environment":"Development","ApplicationName":"API","Timestamp":"2020-02-07T14:02:03.4329033Z"}}

in other case (use only for debugging)

> [20-02-07 13:59:16.16Z INF] Get customer by id: 20

Then you should configure log router to collect logs from container and send it to the Elasticsearch.

If all logs are [structured](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/06/structured-logging-concepts-in-net-series-1/), it improves searching and creating indexes in Kibana.

Comment: Thanks, you wouldn't know the `appsettings.json` equivalent to `ElasticsearchJsonFormatter()`?  At the moment I have `"formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"`.  I have installed `Serilog.formatting.elasticsearch` in nuget.

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, you need to install package `Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch`

Comment: I have just posted this on their github: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/issues/314.  I am configuring Serilog from the `appsettings.json` and not newing up `ElasticsearchJsonFormatter()` in code.  What would this be?

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line `applicationName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(applicationName) ? context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("App:Name") : applicationName;
`

Comment: Just remove this line if you don't need it. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working nicely.  With regards to the application name, its `null` at the moment, will I need to add it to `appsettings,json`? As I like the idea of including it in the logs.

Comment: Ok, will do, just one last question: how do I add my own namespaces to this extension method?  e.g. "mynamespace.myclass = verbose`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context